# What is required to queue a new build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am building within Visual Studio 2012 using this:

[image]

Unless I do a manual check in of the entire solution, it does not seem to build with the latest changes.

**In order to build with the latest source, is it a requirement to check the code into TFS?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is another way. You can *shelve* your code and queue a [private build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181722%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#Private). This allows you to validate the code before checking it in.

You can even make this a requirement for your version control branch by creating a [Gated check-in build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

> In order to build with the latest source, is it a requirement to check the code into TFS?

Yes, the build server will get the latest source from TFS when a build starts. If you have changes on your local computer that you have not checked in they will be included in the build.

Using a build server helps you control exactly what you build and later deploy. Instead of deploying whatever was on a developer machine when you decide to deploy you build a specific version that exists in TFS. By default a build will also create a label that allows you to later recreate the exact version of the source code that was used to perform the build.

Comment: i'm sorry can you clarify whether they will or WILL NOT be included from my local version?

Comment: @IIIIIllllllllIlllllIIIIIIIIlll The build server does not have access to your personal computer. Anything that is on your computer but not in TFS will not be included in the build. If you want changes to be included you need to check them in.